# Why Date Field is not formatting in Data weave?

Tags: mule, dataweave

[image]Hi i have a Date field which is coming as

```
{
"noteDate": "2013-12-18T00:00:00"
}
```

My Dataweave function is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.noteDate  as String {"format": "uuuu-MM-dd"}
//formattedDate: |2020-10-01T23:57:59| as String {format: "uuuu-MM-dd"}, // This is in Documentation
```

The output i am getting is

```
"2013-12-18T00:00:00"
```

Expected Output is

```
"2013-12-18"
```

How i can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.noteDate as Date
```

That is coming in as a string, not as a date. JSON has no concept of dates.

If you wanted to treat it as a DateTime and then apply a string format you could convert it first (shown below) but just casting it to a Date will do the same.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload.noteDate as DateTime) as String { format: "uuuu-MM-dd" }
```